# are the questions from the old site being ported?

Tags: discussion

there were a lot of good questions on the original askaboutprojects.com site - are they being transferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on past experience with betas, they won't get transferred until after the public beta period starts and things look healthy. This will be because the folks who asked the questions in the first place probably aren't beta members here, so they can't see where their questions and answers have gone. If the beta isn't healthy, it will get shut down eventually.