# Current traffic stats

Tags: discussion, statistics

Can we get some update on traffic stats, especially how much comes from different sources (like search engine, direct, referrals)? I think about data similar to what Robert Cartaino published here: h[ttp://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/94/site-not-on-track-to-survive-public-beta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/site-not-on-track-to-survive-public-beta)

It would give us some insight how we're doing in terms of promoting the site.

Btw: who has access to traffic stats?

Answer (score 4):

We generally don't provide specific, per-site traffic statistics. The last update was only two weeks ago and this site is generally doing what is typically expected of a new site — It's currently in a pattern steady horizontal traffic which is typical of early sites. Many sites continue along this horizontal pattern of steady traffic until they reach a "tipping point" where critical mass is reached and they take off with unstoppable growth.

Your search engine traffic has remained steady. But on the rise is your "referring sites" traffic; It has grown from 55% to 62%. That means that lots of new traffic is coming from sites like Twitter, Facebook, and blogs. That means that people are talking about you and coming to see what this site is about. That's a good thing. As long as you are bringing in new traffic from external sources (search engines, social media), that mean you are accumulating *high-quality* questions people are looking for. That is a good sign of more growth to come.

Answer (score 4):

The statistics section in the moderator tools section has a message saying the data is not to be shared publicly.  Therefore, I don't feel it's my place to post that information here as Robert did.

However, I can tell you that the traffic still looks close to what it was previously.  The search engine traffic is still less than 15%.

As far as referring site traffic, your blog is in the top 10, so I would encourage you to continue blogging about the site and doing the things you are doing.  You're definitely making a positive impact both in your leading contributions on the site as well as your referral contributions off the site.

Comment: I don't see a statistics section in the moderator tools. It's for the diamond-mods only right?

Comment: Correct.  This is not available to regular users; however, I do feel that a feature that shows individual stats to users would be useful, especially if you're aiming for the Annoucer, Booster, or Publicist badges.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on the visitors per day metric. It's still hovering around 260-270. It's been that way for a while. That's what Robert is talking about -- horizontal traffic.

Comment: Yes, this is very typical, even of ecommerce websites.  The statistics will show horizontal, traffic sometimes for years, until enough links, brand awareness, and brand loyalty is built up to propel the site traffic into the stratosphere.

Comment: It looks like it spiked up today to almost 300. That's a great sign.

Comment: Those links people are sharing and blogging about are making a difference.