# Do questions about software development process belong here?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are a lot of questions which touch the land somewhere between project management and software development. To show what I think about: agile bonds these areas together pretty tightly so questions on the subject are usually pretty good example here.

[This question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/803/what-about-prince2-fdd-agile-development-with-xp) for example deals with FDD and XP which generally belongs to software development domain.

I believe it will be often very difficult to clearly draw borders between these two domains, but on the other hand I see [trend to split these domains even more](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/many-site-proposals-on-project-management-software-deveopment-methods). So the question is: do we consider software development process as a part of software project management or not? Do questions about software development process belong here?

Comment: I agree it's difficult to draw borders, especially this early on.

Answer (score 1):

I feel it's too early to rule out questions that are sitting right on the line.  The evidence from the metrics so far is that we're [seeing an increase in Referring Sites traffic.](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/current-traffic-stats/121#121)

This means the community finds the site interesting enough to share questions, post blog articles, and share links to the site.  My take is that if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  What we're doing seems to be working.

We should continue to watch what kinds of questions are asked here and support those that are interesting.  As we get more users and more questions, it will be more clear whether or not it would be necessary to break those questions into other topics.

In my opinion, as long as the topic relates to project management, it's on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the earlier thread about only having 3.6 questions per day, I think we should take every PM question we can get, even if it is a bit on the edge.

Plus, the reality is that, at this point, most of the PMs we have on here are software development PMs, so those questions would be right on topic for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this worse, check out the Kanban group in Area51.  I see all three of those as seperate bodies of knowledge though overlaping.  I made the pitch in Kanban that it should focus on Lean concepts of flow, cadence, and queing, but not turn into Lean.

Does everyone see those as three different areas of knowledge?