# Is the questions metric key if the PM site is to avoid being cancelled after beta?

Tags: discussion, beta, site-survival

As [this meta post points out](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/site-not-on-track-to-survive-public-beta) PM-SE is not going to have a strong case for continued existence based on the [5 core measures](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947?phase=beta) published on Area 51.

The metrics published at Area 51 are a bit pessimistic looking, with questions per day perhaps the key driver - more questions will result in more visits, more signups and more avid users.  So I think we should consider driving up the questions asked metric to save the site.

**Questions Per Day**

- <5 Worrying
- 5-15 Okay
- 15+ Excellent

Currently 234 questions have been asked in 47 days, 3.6 per day.

For this to move to an 'Okay' 6 a day requires 540 questions to be asked in the 90 days of beta - that will require an achievable 7 a day from now on.

To move onto 10 a day on average will require 15 questions a day to be asked for the rest of the beta

For just over 15 questions a day to be averaged 25-30 questions will need to be asked every day to the end of the beta.

Unless things radically change I don't see where 25 or so questions every day of the week will come from, this site is simply not going to get an 'excellent' score for questions asked - not unless the current users change their usage patterns drastically or new excited users suddenly appear.

But an 'Okay' metric for questions asked for this site is very achievable if a minimum of 7 questions are asked each day.  The 50 questions on the front page were all asked in the last 9 days - so if everyone simply saw to it that the newest front page only contained questions asked in the last week then we would have 7 questions a day being asked.

To ask a bunch of people to come up with a new question every day is a bit much; but if 25 people agreed to ask a much more realistic 2 questions per week then one of the key metrics would move out of the danger zone.  **If we can't find 25 people prepared to commit something along those lines then perhaps the site was never going to work anyway**.

In PM terms we are behind schedule and need to consider de-scoping aspects of the project to hit the deadline (which the client says is immoveable).

I don't think PM-SE will finish public beta with five 'excellent' metrics - but if the three worrying measures move into 'Okay' the site might yet survive.

**Can we improve the questions metric and will that get an acceptable mix of Okay and Excellent for the five metrics before the 90 days are up?**

Comment: You don't have to manage those stats within 90 days, focus on question rather than getting 7 crappy questions to meet the required stats

Comment: I don't know why people keep saying "stop asking questions." We all have good, solid, specific questions to ask, if we just stop to think a little more. Project management is such an inter-disciplinary field that it's hard to NOT come up with questions about projects.

Comment: Ultimately, it's up to those of us who are committed to do whatever is in our capacity to make the site survive -- blogging about it, linking, talking to people, asking questions, etc.

Comment: Related: https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/856/4271

Answer (score 7):

Please refer to [Robert Cartaino's Answer On How To Make PMSE Win](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/site-not-on-track-to-survive-public-beta/101#101).

In order for this site to move out of beta, it must grow organically.  The only sustainable way to increase the number of questions per day is to **get more traffic from search engines**.  You can help by spreading interesting questions and interesting topics to people in your network, using your social networking tools.

If you have a blog that gets good traffic and that relates to project management, you can pick certain questions, use those as topics for your blog articles, and then include a link to the PMSE question.

If we ask 25 people to post 7 questions per day, or 10 questions per day, or 20 questions per day, we would simply be covering up the symptoms of a much bigger problem.  Eventually, those 25 people will run out of questions to ask.  Not only will we then be back to square one, but we'll also have a front page filled with potentially poor questions.

To make this site succeed, let's focus on the [Publicist, Booster, and Announcer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) badges.  If you can earn these badges, then you will have significantly helped this site grow in a way that will sustain for the lifetime of the site.

Comment: It's up to each of us, individually, to do whatever we can. So let's do it.