# Are the Area 51 metrics right?

Tags: discussion

If there are 235 questions on PM after 47 days of beta, then surely that is 5 questions a day rather than the 3.6 quoted on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947?phase=beta).  Or are some of the questions not counted - and if so, why?

Comment: Closed questions might not be included

Comment: It's also possible the averages are computed using a different time measurement.  For instance, if we looked at the average for the last 4 days, we would see an average of 3.75 questions per day.  Since we're measuring the site's growth, it's more accurate to show the numbers for the last week than since the beginning of time.  If I were the person building the Area 51 stats, that's what I would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a moving average over the last 2 weeks, not all time.

Comment: Which suggests that after an initial surge of questions there has been a mid-season slump.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the period for which the data is measured.  Good to know!