# A Call for Q&A Bloggers: Answering your own Question

Tags: discussion, promotion

Recently, the [community managers reminded us that this is not only acceptable, but desirable to answer your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/155826) by adding an "Answer Your Own Question" checkbox right below "Post your Question" in the post question page.

We have many contributors to this community who have lots of knowledge that they've already shared in their answers. Some of you I know blog regularly, give talks, and are very active members in the broader PM community.

**My question is this:  What do you think about picking your favorite Project Management topic, posting questions that you already know the answer to, and then answering them in Q&A format, kind of like miniature blog posts?**

If you're a long term user on this site, you can help guide contributors by voting to close off-topic or not constructive questions that don't fit the Q&A model, editing content to help contributors write on-topic question, and providing guidance and encouragement through comments.

**Is this a good idea for PMSE? If so, how should we get started? What guidelines should we put in place to make this successful while still ensuring quality over quantity? Who would be interested in contributing in this manner?**

Again, anyone with over 100 reputation can participate in not only posting but also helping define the guidelines for how we should promote and manage this. I do believe StackExchange is run by the community, and I'm looking forward to hearing your thoughts on how we might proceed.

Please add any helpful information below as an answer.

**UPDATE:** Here is the official blog post titled [Encyclopedia Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) that tells more about this new feature.

Comment: The most successful efforts I've seen like this for SE started with a bank of FAQs, for example from a usenet group.  Does such a list of "starter questions" exist?

Comment: @Michael - We have a start a [list of questions that would make great blog articles](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/144/what-are-some-interesting-questions-that-could-be-used-in-a-blog-article-to-help). If any of these topics could be expanded upon, then this could be a good place to start. Do we need to start a new list or do you think adding to this list would be fine?

Comment: Probably a new list, or preferably a list somewhere that already exists that could be made better in a SE Q&A format. Here's a link to the example I was remembering: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-flash-mobs/ The goal in this case was to take already popular/oft-asked questions that were locked away in a place that weren't easily accessible and making them available to the masses on SO.