# Closing down the old site?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

In follow-up to this previous [question](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/are-the-questions-from-the-old-site-being-ported), shouldn't the old [askaboutprojects.com](http://askaboutprojects.com/) site be closed now that this one is running?

Answer (score 1):

Could we keep it open until this site survives Public Beta?  Could the Admin of AskAboutProjects put up a system message pointing people to here for now?

I heard the old site might close for financial reasons, so if we can help point existing users here first, I feel like that might be more helpful.

However, [it's not a good idea to migrate questions during a public beta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/are-the-questions-from-the-old-site-being-ported/5#5), so for now redirection might be best.